# After successfully executing this query, how do go I back to the previous stage in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rollback

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Query:

> UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET ADDRESS = 'Pune' WHERE ID = 6;

After successfully executing this query, how do I back to the previous stage?

I have tried rollback, but it is not working.

My engine is `InnoDB`.

Comment: What's your storage engine (InnoDB, MyISAM, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table engine is not [`InnoDB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html), or you haven't used [`transactions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) for this operation, then it might be not possible.

To have possibility to `ROLLBACK` DML statements (like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries) you should use transaction blocks:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET ADDRESS = 'Pune' WHERE ID = 6;
-- and more DML queries

COMMIT; -- or ROLLBACK;
```

Since transaction was `COMMIT`ed it can not be rolled back. Only option (that I see) is to restore database backup (if it exists).

---

**UPDv1:**

Just as an advice: Before you do any critical changes to database (perform transactions, execute complex scripts, that includes `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s or change data structures with `ALTER`s or `DROP`s) [make a backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/backup-methods.html) of your database.

You may probably restore backup as another database copy, then test script on it. If nothing goes wrong, then perform script for a real database.